# Interface implementation getting lost

Tags: java, oop, decompiling

I have a class like that:

```
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {}
```

but when I compile this using Maven and decompile the file `ClassA.class` using JAD i got only this.

```
public class ClassA {}
```

In another project package this don't happenig...

Someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Is it causing errors? Is `InterfaceA` actually referenced anywhere? Maybe the decompiler optimized it out, although that behavior seems undesirable.

Comment: Yes... It's causing erros on deploy to weblogic.
There is another class inplementing this interface and when I decompile with JAD the implements still there.